Cloth simulation: low object collision - distance corrupt simulation
I have a Blender 4.1.1 downloaded from the Blender site.
I'm trying a cloth simulation and, if I leave the object collision - distance to "0.015" it works correctly; but leave a big distance from the body

If I set this distance to "0.005" the simulation don't take into account the collisions and the cloth fades inside the body

What I'm doing wrong?
This is the blend file
NEW LINK to test file

hello your link asks for an authorization

This one should work: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10h_uj_TWc8yvNf-bMe4_uJiNcIzKOVZf/view?usp=sharing
